# pi zero w + piCore without keyboard and monitor = cannot connect to wifi

Tags: wifi, logfiles

I am new to raspberry pi, I would like to set up a tinycore os. I do not have a keyboard nor a monitor that I can connect through HDMI.
So I'm trying to autoconnect to the wifi so that I can ssh. But it never connects on the network.
I have put the following files on `/opt/`

```
ca_certificates.tcz
firmware-rpi3-wireless.tcz
libiw.tcz
libnl.tcz
ncurses.tcz
openssl.tcz
readline.tcz
wifi.tcz
wireless_tools.tcz
wireless-4.9.22-piCore.tcz
wpa_supplicant.tcz
```

plus the corresponding .md5.txt and .dep files

Here is my `tce/onboot.lst`

```
mc.tcz
openssh.tcz
firmare-rpi3-wireless.tcz
wireless_tools.tcz
wireless-4.9.22-piCore.tcz
wpa_supplicant.tcz
wifi.tcz
```

Here is my `bootlocal.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -Dwext -c/opt/wpa_configure.conf -B &
```

I have set my `wpa_credentials.conf` as it should

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
network={
         ssid=MyBox
         psk=MyPassword
         proto=WPA
         pairwise=TKIP
         group=TKIP
         key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Besides, I cannot read any log file of the boot. I tried to copy the log files in `bootlocal.sh` by adding a line `cp /var/log/messages /opt/messages`, but without success.

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Sure! But before  I even can try that, i need to be able to get an ip adress.

Comment: Most of us use Raspbian. I'm afraid it's not easy to get support from here for piCore (but may be). Have you considered to start with [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) instead?

Comment: Yes I have ! However I cant grab an sd card with 8go of memory, and the application for my raspberry pi is quite minimilastic. I succesfully installed dietpi on my 2go sd card though.